# Нужна ли запятая перед "слегка"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая?

**На поверхности органа виден очаг красного слегка синюшного цвета.**

Answer (score 2):

> ...нужна ли запятая?

Нужны две запятые:

***На поверхности органа виден очаг красного, слегка синюшного, цвета.***

Похожий пример см. у **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4#pp118)**:

> **§ 22.** Уточняющие члены предложения
>
> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и
>   словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это
>   переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего
>   уточняются обстоятельства и определения.
>
> <...>
>
> **4.** Уточняющие определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста и т. д.:
>
> ***...Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, почти заспанным, лицом*** (Т.)